# $T:E\longrightarrow F $ isomorphism. Prove $\dim \langle \vec x_1,\ldots ,\vec x_n\rangle =\dim \langle T(\vec x_1), \ldots,T( \vec x_n)\rangle$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T:E\longrightarrow F $ be an isomorphism. Prove $\dim \big\langle \vec x_1,\ldots ,\vec x_n\big\rangle =\dim \big\langle T(\vec x_1), \ldots,T( \vec x_n)\big\rangle$, for every $\{\vec x_1, \ldots, \vec x_n\}\subset E$.

My proof:

We can say that $A=\langle \vec x_1, \ldots, \vec x_n\rangle$ is a vector space (as a subspace of $E$) and $B=T(A)=\langle T(\vec x_1), \ldots, T(\vec x_n)\rangle$ is a vector space (as a subspace of $F$), as well.

So, we can say we have the isomorphism $T_A: A\longrightarrow B$. Since T is isomorphism$\implies \dim A= \dim B $.

Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a complete proof, until you've proved that restricting an isomorphism to a subspace always generates an isomorphism onto the image...which is what the problem you're trying to solve *asks*.

Hint: what's your definition of "dimension"? How would you compute the dimension of the two spaces in your problem? (Hint: you'd take a linearly independent subset of the $x_i$s for the left...) Suppose $T$, applied to a basis for the left side, was not a basis for the right side? What would that tell you?

Comment: I can easily prove that if $\{\vec x_1,\ldots, \vec x_n\}$ are linearly independent$\implies \{T(\vec x_1),\ldots ,T(\vec x_n)\}$ are linearly independent, as well.

Comment: When the $x$'s are not linearly independent, you can take a maximal linearly independent subset of them. The span of that subset will be what?

Comment: A subspace of $E$ with dimension $\le \dim E$.

Comment: Since it's the *maximal* independent subset of $x_1, ..., x_n$, what can you say about the relationship of its span to $Q = span\langle x_1, \ldots, x_n\rangle$?

Comment: We would have the same subspace.

Comment: OK. If you call that maximal linearly independent subset $U = \{u_1, \ldots, u_p\}$, what can you say about $\{T(u_1), \ldots, T(u_p)\}$, and about its relationship to $\{T(x_1), \ldots, T(x_n)\}$?

Comment: Their spans produce the same subspace  $\implies \dim\langle T(u_1),\ldots,T(u_p)\rangle=\dim \langle T(x_1),\ldots, T(x_n)\rangle$.

Comment: Since $\{T(u_1),\ldots ,T(u_p)\}$ is a basis of $\langle T(u_1), \ldots, T(u_p)\rangle$, we have that $T(x_1),\ldots,T(x_n)$ can be written as a linear combination of $T(u_1),\ldots, T(u_p)$. So, it is that $\langle T(u_1),\ldots, T(u_p)\rangle=\langle T(x_1),\ldots, T(x_n)\rangle$. Right?

Comment: Right...and they're also linearly independent (this takes a tiny bit of proof -- and uses the hypothesis that $T$ is an isomorphism!), so they form a basis for $Q$, hence the dimension of $Q$ is exactly $p$, which is the dimension of the span of the $x$s, and you're done.

Comment: Yeap, thank you. I can do so, as I mentioned in my first comment.